# Cannot fetch data before render

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch

I am try to get data with axios before i render it. I am using axios and getting data in ComponentDidMount. I also tried to get in Component WillMount but still not working how can i solve this problem????

I also tried to get in Component WillMount but still not working, i need the data before render coz  i have to pass to another component.
After that i put on a button and after few second from loaded website it works as expected

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://us-central1-punjabi-music-downloader.cloudfunctions.net/getTracks"
      )
      .then(res => this.setState({ tracks: res.data }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Music tracks</h1>
        {this.state.tracks[0].name}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I RECEIVE `.name is not defined`.

Comment: why you need to get data before render instead of re-render after you got the data? I mean the component should render both "loading" and "loaded" state?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if data is available then only you need to set it like

```
{this.state.tracks && this.state.tracks.length > 0 ? <span>this.state.tracks[0].name</span> : null}
```

Comment: Lol i aldo tried this but i failed to write the condition (i am still at high school). Anyway thank you very much. i was trying it from 2 days